# The security of adding random noise many time pad

Tags: one-time-pad, one-time-password

In may application, I have a series of real number $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_N\}, v_i\in\mathbb{R}$. To protect them, I add a random noise $r\in\mathbb{R}$ to each themselves like one-time-pad encryption scheme. But due to some more requirements of optimization we only want to generate and use a random noise $r$ instead of generating one time pad. Is this model is secure and which level of security can I obtain?

Comment: In my key random noise is similar to random key.

Comment: Ask yourself if your could recognize ciphertext for $\{0,1\}$ from ciphertext for $\{0,2\}$. If the answer is yes, that's a valid Choosen Plaintext attack. Various issues: $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_N\}$ is the notation for a set (where order does not matter), when most of the time plaintext is a vector. In crypto, it is seldom appropriate to use reals (elements of $\Bbb R$) for plaintext and ciphertext, for they have no fixed-size representation. A random elements of $\Bbb R$ is not well defined; and it it was, there's no clear way to share one between two actors;

Comment: Either it is a one-time pad or it isn't, either distributed over a number of bits or some other domain. As long as the domain is long enough and the random number is fully random for each $v_i$ it should count as a one-time pad. As "fully random" is tricky, you should be fine with "random enough" practically speaking. But it is unclear if "random noise" counts as RNG.

Answer (score -4):

Too tricky for a comment...

Conceptually, your scheme is 110% information theoretic secure, as it's a [one time pad](http://users.telenet.be/d.rijmenants/en/onetimepad.htm)($ \downarrow $). But since we tend to use octet based computer architecture these days, $  \mathbb{Z}  $ is more appropriate.

Note 1. Ensure $ |r| \ge |v| $.

Note 2. Don't want to patronise, but the one time pad is thee most contentious and misunderstood aspect of cryptography ever invented. Especially on this forum. Is $r$ truly random or just pseudo-random? It's worrisome that I read 'generate' in a kinda algebraic context...